# Regex for Eclipse/Flash Builder File Search for comments?

Tags: java, regex, apache-flex, eclipse

In Eclipse (and Flash/Flex Builder) you get the option with Ctrl+Shift+F to do a file search and look for a regular expression. Would be a real handy thing to know.

I want to find the word ***negate*** if it appears in a Flex/java comment like the following:

```
// It was negated because
```

or

```
/*
  The negate option was....
*/
```

or

```
/**
 * We have to negate the value
*/
```

Any ideas? Will test them out at http://www.regexplanet.com/simple/index.html

Answer (score 1):

This should do it for you I believe:

(?://.*|/*.*\s*.*)negate

Comment: This finds every occurance of '//' as well as '//..negate...'. Will work on it, thnks

Comment: I just changed the regex, try the new one. I forgot to group the expressions properly. This one seems to work.

Comment: Tried yours, too - and this one works in eclipse, although it doesn't select single words, either. Up vote for that, and kudos.

Comment: It finds negate in comments alright, but also every occurance of negate in the code:( Thnks though, B

Answer (score 1):

Matching only the word "negate" is tricky, because you would need a lookbehind expression (such as `(?<=\/\/.*)negate` to match only "negate"s preceded by `//` and any number of characters), but these are supposed to have a fixed length - which we cannot know, since "negate" could really appear anywhere inside a comment.  I'm afraid I don't know any other way to match single words inside other text.

However, you can find entire comments containing "negate" in eclipse using this RegEx:

```
((//.*negate.*$)|(/\*(.|\r|\n)*negate(.|\r|\n)*\*/))
```

**Edit**: removed some unnecessary backslashes

Comment: Alas, eclipse complains that this regex is too complex, and sends me packing!!

Comment: Just tested it online at the link above, and no matches using the sample text I supplied:(

Comment: That's weird...  I tried both your link and my own eclipse installation! Will check to see if I messed up on my edit.

Comment: Okay, I checked... On the web site, be sure to check the "multiline" option.

Comment: Eclipse does the search, but only for single files, unfortunately.  I'll try to split it up into two separate patterns.